# Illegal Unit of Measure (pt inserted)

Tags: graphics, errors, width, posters

I am trying to insert an image into my poster in the top of my fourth column. I have not had any issues with errors until I actually use `\insertgraphics`. I made sure my image is a jpeg: here is my code

```
\begin{block}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{MP_Oblique_Picture.jpg}
\caption{Method of Solving Oblique Triangle}
\end{figure}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Deriving Formulas for Solving Oblique Triangles}
```

I have messed around with the width, nothing seems to help. I have inserted other images into the same file and I tried to mimic the code I had there, but that did not work either. I still consider myself a latex beginner so anything helps.

Here is the actual error message it gives:

```
./main.aux:19:

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

<to be read again> 

                   a

l.19 \@input{\vskip .aux}
```

Comment: The error seems completely unrelated to the image.

Comment: Welcome! Comment out the image to test. Does the error disappear? We need, ideally, code for a complete but minimal example which we can compile to reproduce the issue. But `\@input{\vskip .aux}` surely seems very screwed up.